# div occupying all the space of a parent

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I have a grid (I'm using semantic-ui), left column has fixed width (e.g. `768px`) and so the right column. I want that content in right column occupy all the height (e.g. `768px`) available. Now it just stacks and the top. See the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/evdymapm/1/

In this right column I have three elements:

```
            <div class="ui horizontal divider">
                Test
            </div>

            <div>
                <div id="about" class="nano">
                    <div class="nano-content">
                        <p> 12:34:56: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;Test&gt; test test
                        <p> 12:34:56: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;Test&gt; test test
                        <p> 12:34:56: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;Test&gt; test test
                        <p> 12:34:56: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;Test&gt; test test
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ui divider"></div>
            <div class="ui action input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="">
                <button class="ui button">Send</button>
            </div>
```

First one is divider, second one is scrollable area and the third one is divider with input. So I want this second element

```
                <div>
                    <div id="about" class="nano">
                        <div class="nano-content">
                            <p> 12:34:56: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;Test&gt; test test
                            <p> 12:34:56: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;Test&gt; test test
                            <p> 12:34:56: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;Test&gt; test test
                            <p> 12:34:56: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;Test&gt; test test
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

to occupy all available space, so that first element will be at the top of the column, second occupy the space (e.g. 90%) and the third one will be at the bottom of the column.

Is that possible? How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.